# Derived set of $(n)/(n+1)$

Tags: real-analysis

What will be the derived set of 
$$
S=\left\{\frac{n}{n+1} \mid n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}\:?
$$
I know it's $\{1\}$. But I am facing problem while proving it.

Comment: Could you include the definition of *derived set*?  Also, how do you know it's $\{1\}$?  That might be the beginning of your proof.

Comment: It is going to be $\{0\}$, since $\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\right|<\epsilon$ for all $n>1/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Have you sketched a picture of $S$ on a number line to get a guess for what the limit points might be?

As mentioned in the comments, the derived set is $\{0\}$. To show this, you need to do two things:

- Show that $0$ is a limit point of $S$. That is, show that any neighborhood $(-h, h)$ of $0$ contains some point of $S$.
- Show that any $x \ne 0$ is not a limit point of $S$. That is, for any $x \ne 0$, find some neighborhood $(x-h, x+h)$ that does not contain any point of $S$ (except possibly $x$ itself).

Comment: So is *derived set* the closure?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The [derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)) refers to the set of limit points.